# Visual Studio Xamarin Forms project is not creating project dll file under bin/debug/netstandard2.0 directory

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

I create new Xamarin Forms project in Visual Studio 2019. But it gives below error. When i check project directory WebViewXamarinApp.dll file is not created.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error       System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Users\cemse\source\repos\WebViewXamarinApp\WebViewXamarinApp\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\WebViewXamarinApp.dll'.
> File name: 'C:\Users\cemse\source\repos\WebViewXamarinApp\WebViewXamarinApp\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\WebViewXamarinApp.dll'
> at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
> at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
> at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
> at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.FilterAssemblies.RunTask()
> at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.AndroidTask.Execute()   WebViewXamarinApp.Android

Comment: It is likely that another error is causing this issue. Can you see any other compilation errors?

Comment: It might be worth deleting the bin and obj folders in the target platform directory and trying the build again.

Comment: @ivbtar You have this error message in blank xamarin.forms? What is `WebViewXamarinApp.dll file`?

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm having the same problem